# OverFlowException on Oracle ODBC RowCount

Tags: odbc, 64-bit

I'm using NHibernate to select an entity from an Oracle database through ODBC.

This works fine on a 32bit system, but on x64 the following error occurs: It seems the rowcount is not in a correct format?

(ODBC part)

```
Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcStatementHandle.RowCount(SQLLEN& rowCount)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetRowCount()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.FirstResult()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor     session)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean     returnProxies)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.LoadEntity(ISessionImplementor session, Object id, IType identifierType, Object optionalObject, String     optionalEntityName, Object optionalIdentifier, IEntityPersister persister)
```

(NHibernate part, but I doubt the problem is situated here):

```
could not load an entity: (Simple NHIbernate Query, works on x86)

   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.LoadEntity(ISessionImplementor session, Object id, IType identifierType, Object optionalObject, String     optionalEntityName, Object optionalIdentifier, IEntityPersister persister)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader.Load(ISessionImplementor session, Object id, Object optionalObject, Object optionalId)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader.Load(Object id, Object optionalObject, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Load(Object id, Object optionalObject, LockMode lockMode, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.LoadFromDatasource(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType     options)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.DoLoad(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.Load(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.ProxyOrLoad(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.OnLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Get(String entityName, Object id)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Get(Type entityClass, Object id)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Get[T](Object id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue:

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=4548988

quote from above website:

Thats a known issue - bug 9793452 .

It's not NHibernate invoking rowcount, its the .NET framework.

If I recall correctly, there's a patch available for 11.2 in the latest patch levels.
Backports to 10204 and 10205 are in progress.
The behavior doesnt occur on 11107.